# Вывод функции в SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

В базе данных функция GetVozr, которая возвращает возраст человека согласно 2 параметрам:
[[[[[@dr](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) и [[[[[@from](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm).
Мне нужно сделать запрос к базе данных, который бы выводил фамилию человека и возраст его.
В запросе p_fam - фамилия человека, base - название базы, данные из строк p_dr и s_datevid соответствуют [[[[[@dr](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) и [[[[[@from](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm)](/users/22975/fromm).
Но на выходе ничего не выводится. Помогите исправить.

Вот мой запрос:

```
DECLARE @dr datetime ,  
 @from datetime   
SELECT  p_fam , GetVozr(@dr ,@from)   
FROM base WHERE  base.p_dr =@dr AND base.s_datevid = @from
```

P.S. Бд MS SQLSERVER.

Comment: Для чего нужны объявленные и неинициализированные переменные? Почему просто не передавать в функцию значения p_dr и s_datevid?

Comment: @null GetVozr(base.p_dr ,base.s_datevid) сделал, и всё заработало. Спасибо за совет. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было сразу передать в функцию `GetVozr(base.p_dr ,base.s_datevid)`,
а `Where` убрать.